# Windows hello won't setup on brand new computer

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account, windows-hello

So I go into `Settings --> Accounts --> Sign-in options` to set up windows hello, and everything goes well until I try to set up a PIN...

[image]

It loads for a few seconds then I get this. I am online and have tried this on several different Wi-Fi networks. I've tried signing in with my Skype and my hotmail, but to no avail. After I put in my password, regardless of whether or not it is correct, I always get this:

[image]

And FYI...

I have gotten similar errors with other Windows services

Also...

[image]

Comment: Maybe, try again later?

Comment: @Appleoddity I've been trying on and off for a week or two

Comment: @FracturedRetina  - You should try changing your DNS server.  I have seen numerous questions submitted to SU, with regards to this issue, which were solved by third-party DNS server.  Knowing what part of the world you are in would also help come to a conclusion which would result in an answer being submitted.

Comment: @Ramhound United States. And how would I go about doing that btw?

Comment: How to chnage your DNS server the same way you have always done it.